# How to convert String to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

****UPDATED

I am trying to populate json to listview , but here I'm facing an error in converting String to json , how can i solve this problem ?

Main Activity

```
   public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

MainArrayAdapter adapter;
ListView lv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.main_actionbar_title);

    adapter = new MainArrayAdapter(new ArrayList<Posts>() , this);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    (new AsyncListViewLoader()).execute("http://almahdy-news.com/hesham.php");


}


private  class AsyncListViewLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Posts>> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Posts> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        dialog.dismiss();
        adapter.setItemList(result);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Posts> doInBackground(String... params) {
        List<Posts> result = new ArrayList<Posts>();

        try {
            URL u = new URL(params[0]);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            byte[] b = new byte[2048];
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            while (is.read(b) != -1)
                baos.write(b);


            String JSONResp = new String(baos.toByteArray() , Charset.defaultCharset());

            //JSONResp = URLEncoder.encode(JSONResp, "utf-8");

            Log.d("TAG" , JSONResp);

            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(JSONResp);

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

                result.add(convertData(arr.getJSONObject(i)));
            }

            return result;

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();

            Log.d("Throwable" , t.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }


    private Posts convertData(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        String postContent = obj.getString("post_content");
        String postID = obj.getString("post_id");
        String postTitle = obj.getString("post_title");
        String userNickname = obj.getString("user_nicename");
        String postDate = obj.getString("post_date");
        String commentCount = obj.getString("comment_count");

        Log.d("TAG" , obj.toString());

        return new Posts(postContent, postID, postTitle, userNickname, postDate, commentCount);
    }
}
```

}

Class Posts

```
public class Posts implements Serializable {
    private String postContent;
    private String postID;
    private String postTitle;
    private String userNickname;
    private String postDate;
    private String commentCount;

    public Posts(String postContent, String postID, String postTitle, String userNickname , String postDate , String commentCount) {
        super();
        this.postContent = postContent;
        this.postID = postID;
        this.postTitle = postTitle;
        this.userNickname = userNickname;
        this.postDate = postDate;
        this.commentCount = commentCount;
    }

    public String getPostContent() {
        return postContent;
    }

    public void setPostContent(String postContent) {
        this.postContent = postContent;
    }

    public String getPostID() {
        return postID;
    }

    public void setPostID(String postID) {
        this.postID = postID;
    }

    public String getPostTitle() {
        return postTitle;
    }

    public void setPostTitle(String postTitle) {
        this.postTitle = postTitle;
    }

    public String getUserNickname() {
        return userNickname;
    }

    public void setUserNickname(String userNickname) {
        this.userNickname = userNickname;
    }

    public String getPostDate() {
        return postDate;
    }

    public void setPostDate(String postDate) {
        this.postDate = postDate;
    }

    public String getCommentCount() {
        return commentCount;
    }

    public void setCommentCount(String commentCount) {
    this.commentCount = commentCount;
    }
}
```

here is the error

> 8258-8284/com.anabil.alel_mahdy W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException:
>   Unterminated object at character 5929 of
>   [{"post_content":"\u0627\u0634\u0643\u0631 \u0627\u0644
>   \u0628\u062f\u0627\u062d \u0639\u0644\u064a
>   \u0627\u0644\u062d\u0641\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0646\u0638\u0645
>   \u0648\u062a\u062d\u0645\u0644\u0647\u0645 \u0643\u0644\u0641\u0647
>   \u0627\u0644\u062d\u0641\u0644 \u0643\u0627\u0645\u0644
>   \u0648\u0627\u0634\u0643\u0631  \u0643\u0644 \u0645\u0646
>   \u0633\u0627\u0647\u0645 \u0641\u064a \u0646\u062c\u0627\u062d
>   \u0627\u0644\u062d\u0641\u0644 \u0645\u0646
>   \u0627\u0639\u0644\u0627\u0645\u064a\u064a\u0646
>   \u0648\u0634\u0639\u0631\u0627\u0621
>   \u0648\u0645\u0646\u0634\u062f\u064a\u0646 .
>   ","post_id":"1090","post_title":"\u0634\u0643\u0631
>   \u0648\u062a\u0642\u062f\u064a\u0631
>   (\u0662)","user_nicename":"\u0622\u0644
>   \u0645\u0647\u062f\u064a","post_date":"2015-05-01
>   21:30:58","comment_count":"1","comments":[{"comment_ID":"188","comment_post_ID":"1090","comment_author":"\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f
>   \u0627\u0644\u0642\u062d\u0637\u0627\u0646\u064a
>   ","comment_author_email":"azsx100100@gmail.com","comment_author_url":"","comment_author_IP":"","comment_date":"0000-00-00
>   00:00:00","comment_date_gmt":"0000-00-00
>   00:00:00","comment_content":"\u062a\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0647\u0644
>   \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0643\u0631\u064a\u0645 \u064a\u0628\u0648
>   \u0645\u0628\u0627\u0631\u0643 \u0648\u0646\u062a
>   \u0648\u0627\u0641\u064a \u0627\u0648 \u0645\u062d\u0632\u0645
>   \u0638\u0641\u0631 \u0648\u0645\u062c\u0645\u0644 \u0628\u0646\u064a
>   \u0639\u0645\u0643
>   ","comment_karma":"0","comment_approved":"1","comment_agent":"","comment_type":"","comment_pa��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������rent":"0","user_id":"0"}],"image":"\u0662\u0660\u0661\u0665-\u0660\u0665-\u0660\u0662 \u0660\u0660:\u0663\u0660:\u0665\u0666.jpg","size":"13"},{"post_content":"\u0627\u0634\u0643\u0631
>   \u0631\u0628\u0639\u064a \u0648\u062a\u0627\u062c
>   \u0631\u0627\u0633\u064a \u0648\u0645\u062d\u0632\u0645
>   \u0627\u0644\u0638\u0641\u0631 \u0627\u0644 \u0645\u0647\u062f\u064a
>   \u0639\u0644\u0626 \u062a\u0643\u0631\u064a\u0645\u064a
>   \u0647\u0630\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0633\u0627\u0621
>   \u0634\u0643\u0631\u0627 \u064a\u0622\u0644 \u062e\u0645\u064a\u0633
>   \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0648\u062d\u0648\u0634  \u0648\u0622\u0644
>   \u0648\u0628\u0631 \u0648\u0622\u0644 \u0647\u0644\u0627\u0644
>   \u0648\u0622\u0644 \u0647\u062c\u0627\u0631 \u0648\u0622\u0644
>   \u0645\u0642\u0637\u0631 \u0648\u0628\u064a\u0636
>   \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0648\u062c\u064a\u0647\u0643\u0645
>   ","post_id":"1088","post_title":"\u0634\u0643\u0631
>   \u0648\u062a\u0642\u062f\u064a\u0631
>   (\u0661)","user_nicename":"\u0622\u0644
>   \u0645\u0647\u062f\u064a","post_date":"2015-05-01
>   21:25:46","comment_count":"3","comments":[{"comment_ID":"190","comment_post_ID":"1088","comment_author":"\u0630\u064a\u0628
>   \u0633\u0639\u064a\u062f
>   \u0627\u0628\u0648\u0636\u0631\u064a\u0633","comment_author_email":"zeeb1474@hotmail.com","comment_author_url":"","comment_author_IP":"","comment_date":"2015-05-01
>   21:25:46","comment_date_gmt":"2015-05-01
>   21:25:46","comment_content":"\u062a\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0 05-02
>   04:50:42.272    8258-8284/com.anabil.alel_mahdy W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450) 05-02
>   04:50:42.272    8258-8284/com.anabil.alel_mahdy W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:394) 05-02
>   04:50:42.272    8258-8284/com.anabil.alel_mahdy W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100) 05-02
>   04:50:42.272    8258-8284/com.anabil.alel_mahdy W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.json.JSONTokener.readArray(JSONTokener.java:430) 05-02
>   04:50:42.272    8258-8284/com.anabil.alel_mahdy W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:103) 05-02
>   04:50:42.272    8258-8284/com.anabil.alel_mahdy W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:92) 05-02 04:50:42.272
>   8258-8284/com.anabil.alel_mahdy W/System.err﹕ at
>   org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:108) 05-02 04:50:42.272
>   8258-8284/com.anabil.alel_mahdy W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.anabil.alel_mahdy.Main$AsyncListViewLoader.doInBackground(Main.java:96)
>   05-02 04:50:42.272    8258-8284/com.anabil.alel_mahdy W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.anabil.alel_mahdy.Main$AsyncListViewLoader.doInBackground(Main.java:52)
>   05-02 04:50:42.272    8258-8284/com.anabil.alel_mahdy W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 05-02 04:50:42.272
>   8258-8284/com.anabil.alel_mahdy W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 05-02
>   04:50:42.272    8258-8284/com.anabil.alel_mahdy W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 05-02
>   04:50:42.272    8258-8284/com.anabil.alel_mahdy W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   05-02 04:50:42.272    8258-8284/com.anabil.alel_mahdy W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   05-02 04:50:42.272    8258-8284/com.anabil.alel_mahdy W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Comment: It appears to be a JSON data problem. The exception is caused by `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: " \u0"`.

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked the whole JSON, but it seems that the following entry is invalid:

> "post_title":"\u0623\u0628\u0648\u0633\u0639\u064a\u062f \u0648\u0623\u \u0648\u064a\u0639\u0627\u0641\u064a\u0647\u0645 ",

It seems that '\u ' (\u and a blank space after) isn't accepted as a valid character.

If your intention is just a blank space between the text, you may just leave the blank space without the \u.

Comment: yea 05-01 13:40:36.933    4172-4191/com.anabil.alel_mahdy D/Throwable﹕ java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: " \u0"
, its arabic letters ,  do u have any solution to handle it because its not my own web service?

Comment: But from the URL your are showing in your code, the JSON there is correct, there is no such '\u0' nor '\u ' only characters.

You can download it manually and place on some json parser, and it will work just fine.

Maybe there is something wrong with your request encode?

Comment: here i dont get the complete JSON values from the web service